# Unable to train model using Microsoft CustomSpeech service

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, speech, microsoft-speech-platform

A half year ago I've already successfully trained multiple models using 'Audio + human labeled transcript' data in [Microsoft speech portal](https://speech.microsoft.com). Now I wanted to train a new model but I only get the error message:

```
The base model isn't valid for this operation.
```

I tried to train the baseline model '20200115' and the older one '20190927'. Both failed with the error message above.

I already checked my audio data, which fits the [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-test-and-train). The audio files are wav-files, 16-bit PCM, 1 channel.

I've also tried to create a new model using the old data which I had used to create the currently working model. This data is still available in speech portal so I had not to upload it again. For this I used the same baseline model '20190927' and got the error message too.

So Microsoft, is there anything you've changed? Is the [website about data requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-test-and-train) still up to date? Or is this a bug?

What can i do to train a new model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue and a hotfix is currently being deployed. Because of the current situation the deployments takes longer than usual and will complete until the end of the week.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A kind request for the future: it would be great if problems that restrict the use of the speech portal were published somewhere. (If that's already the case, I pull it back, but I haven't found anything of the sort). In my case, that would have saved me a lot of the work that went into double checking my data. Regards...